# Celery Task never runs in django

Tags: django

I have created scheduled task in my task.py but it never appears to run. I have restarted my workers and normal tasks run just fine. As I'm new to this, have I missed something, is there a setting in my settings I need?

I don't get any errors this is my task.py

```
  from celery.task import Task
  from celery.decorators import task
  from celery.task import PeriodicTask
  from datetime import timedelta

class ProcessScheduledRequests(PeriodicTask):
    run_every = timedelta(minutes=5)

    def run(self, **kwargs):

       process_something()
```

Comment: are you using celery? please provide more info

Comment: maybe show your task.py

Comment: Are you using celery or django-celery?

Comment: django-celery i.e. djcelery

Comment: in my django admin I an see i have something called periodic tasks an I use that?

Comment: this sounds like you're using something pre-built? if so what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Running Periodic Tasks

I'm not sure what you've tried so far, or what your `settings.py` file looks like but here are some ways to get djcelery to run scheduled tasks.

1) In your `tasks.py`, create a task and use the `celery.decorators.periodic_task` decorator. e.g.

```
from celery.task.schedules import crontab   
from celery.decorators import periodic_task 

@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour=”*”, minute=”*”, day_of_week=”*”)) 
def a_periodic_task(): 
        print “Hello World!”
```

or

```
@celery.decorators.periodic_task(run_every=datetime.timedelta(minutes=5))
def a_periodic_task(): 
        print “Hello World!”
```

2) In your `celery.conf` file use the `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE` setting like so:

```
from datetime import timedelta

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "runs-every-30-seconds": {
        "task": "tasks.add",
        "schedule": timedelta(seconds=30),
        "args": (16, 16)
     },
}
```

You can read more about this in the [periodic task documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html).

Though please remeber that you must start celery in [beat mode](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#starting-the-scheduler) by:

```
python manage.py celeryd -B
```

And also check you've done all the [installation steps](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery) including adding `djcelery` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` and running `python manage.py syncdb` (or `python manage.py migrate djcelery` if you're using south)

#### Deployment

The [celery documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html) has a great section on daemonising your celery processes for deployment including an [example django configuration for beat mode](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html#generic-initd-celerybeat-django-example).

**From the Docs:**

> ```
> # Where the Django project is.
> CELERYBEAT_CHDIR="/opt/Project/"
>
> # Name of the projects settings module.
> export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="settings"
>
> # Path to celerybeat
> CELERYBEAT="/opt/Project/manage.py celerybeat"
>
> # Extra arguments to celerybeat
> CELERYBEAT_OPTS="--schedule=/var/run/celerybeat-schedule"
> ```

Comment: Ok it could that that I don;t use beat mode as I use Apache and demonize celery to run at startup do I need to change my Apache config?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more information on deployment